# Laravel exception when I try to create a test for a link with PestPHP

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, pestphp

I have that kind of problem when I try to create a test for a Link:

> Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames

```php
$response = $this->get('/odata/dim_regions');
```

Error details:

```
Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames

  at vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php:501
    497▕      * are most of the time sub-requests of the main one.
    498▕      */
    499▕     public function __clone()
    500▕     {
  ➜ 501▕         $this->query = clone $this->query;
    502▕         $this->request = clone $this->request;
    503▕         $this->attributes = clone $this->attributes;
    504▕         $this->cookies = clone $this->cookies;
    505▕         $this->files = clone $this->files;

  1   vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php:501
  2   vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php:502
```

I'm using PestPHP.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking `Request` to `clone` its `$request` property inside the `__clone` method. That's infinite recursion.

You don't need to override it, or you can always write `$this->request = $this;` after every property.